# How to avoid Windows Defender SmartScreen from installer when user download?

Tags: windows, signing

I understand the code signing.

But when I try to download some application, it doesn't even have code signing.

And it can still open without the Windows Defender blue screen.

Example: http://www.eainstall.com/download

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The Windows SmartScreen alert will go away after enough people download it.

If your software is not that popular then the warning will never go away and there is not much you can do about it.

> SmartScreen checks files that you download from the web against a list of reported malicious software sites and programs known to be unsafe. If it finds a match, SmartScreen will warn you that the download has been blocked for your safety. [SmartScreen also checks the files that you download against a list of files that are well known](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17443/windows-internet-explorer-smartscreen-filter-faq) and downloaded by many people who use Internet Explorer. If the file that you're downloading isn't on that list, SmartScreen will warn you.

[Microsoft SmartScreen & Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/):

> Code signing is important
>   to our reputation intelligence because this higher level identity allows us to build
>   reputation across multiple programs signed by a publisher. It is also important
>   for publishers because signed programs inherit the reputation of the certificate
>   with which they are signed; this means every program a publisher distributes doesn’t
>   need to build reputation individually.

...

> Programs signed by an EV code signing certificate can immediately establish reputation
>   with SmartScreen reputation services even if no prior reputation exists for that
>   file or publisher.

Comment: If use FTP link instead http will help?

Comment: No, it looks at the .exe file as well.